# Powershell selection validation failing

Tags: powershell

I am having some issues with a dynamic picklist I am generating for a script.  I can see it return the list of options and I can select each of them.  However the validation I have is not working as I would have expected.

```
Write-Host "Gathering cluster information..." -foreground Green
$allclusters = Get-Cluster | Sort Name
$allHosts = $allclusters | Get-VMHost
Write-Host "Found " $allclusters.count " containing " $allHosts.count " Hosts." -Foreground Green
# LoopMain Start
Do {
$userMenuChoice = "y"
Write-Host "Select Cluster to patch:" -Foreground Yellow
for($i=0;$i -le $allclusters.length-1;$i++)
{"[{0}] - {1}" -f $i,$allclusters[$i]}
# Select VMCluster
Write-Host ""
    Write-Host "Which Cluster would you like to use (0 to"($allclusters.length-1)")" -ForegroundColor Cyan -NoNewLine ; $clusterSelect =      Read-Host " "
 Write-Host ""

 # Validate selection
 IF ($clusterSelect -le ($allclusters.length-1))
    {
    Write-Host "Selection is valid"
    # Display item from clusterarray
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host "You selected " -NoNewLine ; Write-Host      $allclusters[$clusterSelect] -ForegroundColor Cyan -NoNewLine ;      $clusterSelectCont = Read-Host ". Shall we continue? (Y/N)"
    }
    ELSE
    {
    Write-Host "Selection is not valid"
    $clusterSelectCont = "n"
    }
```

The picklist will work for some number but not all.  For example I can select number 12 form the list and everything is fine but number 7 fails.  Is there something fundamentally wrong with the way I have created the picklist or is it the validation that is failing perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, so discussed with a colleague here and the suggestion was to cast the variable to an integer using the following line:

```
[int]$clusterSelect = $clusterSelect
```

This now validates as expected and I can select all values without issue.